# What parts are in each bag for the Star Wars Death Star 75159?

Tags: sets, star-wars

I have two opened death stars. Some bags are unopened and others are mixed. I need a checklist of what comes in each bag.

I would like to sell one and keep one.

Comment: The worst case scenario would be to go through the instructions page by page (the pages with the mixed bags) and collect the parts listed there. I would think the effort is not too big if you reasonably sort the parts before flipping through the pages.

Comment: I would build one first. If you have 2 sets if you build 1 the left over pecies should be the other set.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea that might just work for you. 
You clearly have two of everything that you need, so I recommend use Bricklink and go through your list selecting the quantity of bricks required from the pile of bricks that have been opened. That should leave you a pile that you do not need (for the second build)
This will be a good starting point.
Good luck.